# Forcefully Replacing Existing Files during Extracting File using System.IO.Compression?

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to extract all files in a folder

```
        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream))
        {
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(location);
        }
```

But if one file exist then it throws an exception. Is there is any way to tell the Compression API to replace the existing files.

I found one way is to get all the file names first then check whether file exist and delete it. But this is somehow very costly for me.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I have created an extension. any comment to it improve will be appreciated,

```
public static class ZipArchiveExtensions
{
    public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive archive, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwrite)
    {
        if (!overwrite)
        {
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
            return;
        }

        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
        string destinationDirectoryFullPath = di.FullName;

        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
        {
            string completeFileName = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryFullPath, file.FullName));

            if (!completeFileName.StartsWith(destinationDirectoryFullPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                throw new IOException("Trying to extract file outside of destination directory. See this link for more info: https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability");
            }

            if (file.Name == "")
            {// Assuming Empty for Directory
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName));
                continue;
            }
            file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible using ZipFile builtin class?

Answer (score 23):

This code will not throw exception when the folder is not exist, instead of that it will create the folder.

```
public static class ZipArchiveExtensions
{
    public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive archive, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwrite)
    {
        if (!overwrite)
        {
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
            return;
        }
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
        {
            string completeFileName = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryName, file.FullName);
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

            if (file.Name != "")
                file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JABFreeware, as @user960567 said "any comment to it improve will be appreciated," i just add couple of lines to prevent throwing exceptions!
if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

Comment: This is a more robust solution than the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory` already checks for existence and doesn't throw. Now you check twice.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this: [Creating zip files easily in .NET 4.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET-4-5). Your problem seems to be adressed. Alternatively, you can also check [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 7):

Since .NET Standard 2.1, it's as easy as setting `overwriteFiles` to true in:
`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(string sourceFile, string destDir, Encoding entryNameEncoding, bool overwriteFiles)`

```
Example:
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("c:\\file.zip","c:\\destination_folder", Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

Comment: It's always better to explain the answer in few words that how it is solving the problem :)

Comment: as far as I know, does `ExtractToDictionary` not take a boolean value to allow overwriting

Comment: That was much easier than all the other answers.

Comment: @sxeros There's an overload that allows a boolean as of .NET Standard 2.1. Probably should mention this in the answer.

Comment: That's only available on .NET Core, not .NET Framework, FYI

Comment: This is the best answer out of all.

Answer (score 6):

As I'm a total Linq fan, the Linq-ish way just for reference:

```
using (var strm = File.OpenRead(zipPath))
using (ZipArchive a = new ZipArchive(strm))
{
    a.Entries.Where(o => o.Name == string.Empty && !Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(basePath, o.FullName))).ToList().ForEach(o => Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(basePath, o.FullName)));
    a.Entries.Where(o => o.Name != string.Empty).ToList().ForEach(e => e.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(basePath, e.FullName), true));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can extract files to some temp directory and than copy files with the 
"File.Copy" with the ovveride option true to your destination directory

I know that it's not a perfect solution , but this way you do not need to
check if file exist

Comment: I have also this tip in my mind but it is very costly for me.

Comment: I think you do not have other option, except using other framework

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method that takes a path to the zip file.

Based on the accepted answer.

```
    public void ExtractZipFileToDirectory(string sourceZipFilePath, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwrite)
    {
        using (var archive = ZipFile.Open(sourceZipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            if (!overwrite)
            {
                archive.ExtractToDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
                return;
            }

            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
            string destinationDirectoryFullPath = di.FullName;

            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
            {
                string completeFileName = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryFullPath, file.FullName));

                if (!completeFileName.StartsWith(destinationDirectoryFullPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    throw new IOException("Trying to extract file outside of destination directory. See this link for more info: https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability");
                }

                if (file.Name == "")
                {// Assuming Empty for Directory
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName));
                    continue;
                }
                file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something I noticed is that this will keep the original file's creation time. You can add `File.SetCreationTimeUtc(completeFileName, file.LastWriteTime.UtcDateTime);` after `file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);` to fix this.

Comment: There is also a bug where nested directories are not created properly. Adding `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName));` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is useful when you have zip file path

```
public static class ZipArchiveHelper
    {
        public static void ExtractToDirectory(string archiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwrite)
        {
            if (!overwrite)
            {
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(archiveFileName, destinationDirectoryName);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(archiveFileName))
                {

                    foreach (var file in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        var completeFileName = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryName, file.FullName);
                        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName);

                        if (!Directory.Exists(directory) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

                        if (file.Name != "")
                            file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
                    }

                }
            }            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I'm using DotNetZip download from nugget.
I just simply use this code.
This will auto replace the files in the directory if exists.
"OverwriteSilently" !

```
using (ZipFile archive = new ZipFile(@"" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\thezipfile.zip"))
{
     archive.ExtractAll(@"" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little remade method from the answer to create all the folders

```
public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive archive, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwrite)
{
    if (!overwrite)
    {
        archive.ExtractToDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
        return;
    }
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
    {
        string completeFileName = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryName, file.FullName);
        if (file.Name == "")
        {// Assuming Empty for Directory
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName));
            continue;
        }
        // create dirs
        var dirToCreate = destinationDirectoryName;
        for (var i = 0; i < file.FullName.Split('/').Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var s = file.FullName.Split('/')[i];
            dirToCreate = Path.Combine(dirToCreate, s);
            if (!Directory.Exists(dirToCreate))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirToCreate);
        }
        file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to dodge including that blob of code is to simply delete the files before extracting the archive with `del`:

```
del (location + "\*")
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream))
{
  archive.ExtractToDirectory(location);
}
```

It's not exactly what the OP wanted, but it is compact.

Answer (score 0):

A way better code,

> No check for if the directory exist (it will check it automatically while creating it)

> Zero heap allocation (instead of foreach used for)

Usage

```cs
using var stream = someStream;
using var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(stream);
zipArchive.ExtractToDirectoryEx(path);
```

```cs
public static class ZipArchiveExtensions
{
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "ForCanBeConvertedToForeach")]
    public static void ExtractToDirectoryEx(this ZipArchive source, string destinationDirectoryName)
    {
        var entries = source.Entries;
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
        {
            var entry = entries[i];
            var completeFileName = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryName, entry.FullName);
            var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            if (entry.Name != string.Empty)
            {
                entry.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, overwrite: true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```